# Image is not displaying on the command button instead displayed "Submit Query". What could be the issue?

Tags: commandbutton

I tried to display the command button as an image button and for that, i have added image attribute to the button and used a gif from static resource. I have used the following html to achieve this, but not able to do that. What could be the issue? Please advice.

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!GenerateCSV}" id="btnOpenSalesCSV" image="{!URLFOR($Resource.DownloadImage,'DownloadImage.gif')}" />
```

[image]

**Update:**

Rendered HTML for the button,

```
<td class="dataCol first " colspan="2">

    <input id="j_id0:myForm:j_id36:j_id37:btnOpenSalesCSV" class="btn" type="image" name="j_id0:myForm:j_id36:j_id37:btnOpenSalesCSV" src="/resource/1400068785000/DownloadImage/DownloadImage.gif"></input>

</td>
```

Image i am trying to display on the Command button.

[image]

Added screen shot of the inspect element window below on the bottom of the page.

[image]

Comment: Did you inspect the raw HTML to see what the button is being displayed as in the page?

Comment: Thanks @BarCotter. I have updated my question with the rendered HTML for the button. Also, added the .gif image which i am trying to display on the button.

Comment: Can you navigate directly to `/resource/1400068785000/DownloadImage/DownloadImage.gif` to make sure that the image is available and displayed correctly?

Comment: The raw HTML doesnt correspond your screenshot. The input button does not have a value of "Submit Query" which the button in your screenshot does.

Comment: Barcotter, that is the raw HTML which i took from Firefox Inspect Element option. Please see the screen shot in added in my question.

Comment: @BarCotter, the image did not display and shows an error as follows, The image "view-source:https://c.na15.visual.force.com/resource/1400088230000/UtilityImages/Images/sort_desc.png" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this isn't working, but another way to add images to a visualforce page is to store the image as a document, store the id of the document in custom settings, and then store the URL of the image in your controller:

```
public string getDocumentLogoUrl()
{

    Org_Settings__c custSettings = Org_Settings__c.getInstance();        
    string strOrgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
    String strDocUrl = '/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id='+custSettings.Logo__c+'&oid=' + strOrgId;
    return strDocUrl;
 }
```

You can then call this from your visualforce page like so:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!GenerateCSV}" id="btnOpenSalesCSV" image="{!DocumentLogoUrl}" />
```

Probably not the easiest solution, but when I was having trouble with images this worked for me.